# What does the distribute tag do in a Pentaho Kettle ETL step?

Tags: distribution, etl, pentaho, kettle

What is the difference between `<distribute>Y</distribute>` and `<distribute>N</distribute>`?  In the Spoon user interface, how does this value change?

```
  <step>
    <name>Not Empty</name>
    <type>Dummy</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>N</distribute>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>1412</xloc>
      <yloc>492</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this page at the wiki:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Partitioning+data+with+PDI

the other option its to copy the rows to all the next steps.

Comment: That was one step containing this tag, but that distribute tag exists in dozens of different step types.  I was more interested in that tag and not the partitioning, because it seems that it changed when we saved the scripts, but I don't know how it happened.